# Blowing hot air on a plate containing water similar to blowing on a cup of coffee

Tags: thermodynamics

imagine, we blow hot air on a plate which contains water at room temperature, constantly in an open system. Will it ever become ice? at least in theory or is there any constrains for it to happen?

Reference-[Why do some hand dryers blow hot air?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127522/why-do-some-hand-dryers-blow-hot-air) .

Comment: Does the plate contain the water, or does the air contain the water?

Comment: Read up Second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: Plate contain the water.